# Nonetype object in write method odoo

Tags: python, odoo

When I edit the sale order and save, credit and debit field got nonetype error. How can I solve it?

```py
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    logging.info("create Mehtod+++++++++++++++++++++")
    logging.info(type(vals.get('credit')))
    if vals.get('credit') < vals.get('debit'):
        vals['check'] = True 
        logging.info("Create fisrt++++++++++++++++")
    else:
        vals['check'] = False
        logging.info("Create second++++++++++++++")
    return super(sale_credit, self).create(vals)

def write(self,vals):
    logging.info("Write Mehtod+++++++++++++++++++++++")
    # logging.info(vals['debit'])
    logging.info(type(vals.get('credit')))
    logging.info(vals)

    if vals['credit'] >= vals['debit']:
        logging.info("FIrst write+++++++++++++")
        vals['check'] = False
    else:
        vals['check'] = True
    return super(sale_credit, self).write(vals)
```

I got the following error log:

```
 File "/home/akkl/odoo13_ENTERPRISE/odoo13_5555/odoo13_5555-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/akkl/odoo13_ENTERPRISE/odoo13_5555/odoo13_5555-server/odoo/api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/akkl/odoo13_ENTERPRISE/odoo13_5555/odoo13_5555-server/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akkl/UMG/customer_credit_limit/models/models.py", line 115, in write
    if vals['credit'] >= vals['debit']:
KeyError: 'credit'
```

Comment: Show your error log

Comment: @Burning Alcohol.Check my error log

Answer (score 0):

If *vals* is a dictionary, when has no element with key = *'credit'*, the *vals.get('credit')* returns *None*.

You should check if vals.get('credit') is not None before the "*if vals['credit'] >= vals['debit']:*"